# Spring Reactor Exception

Tags: spring, exception, reactive

I get the following exception using Spring React.

My method:

```
public Mono<A> getA(
    @PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
    return <<some service call that returns Mono<A> >>;
}
```

Exception:

> 019-03-22 17:55:59,518 priority=ERROR app_name=sync
>   thread=reactor-http-nio-1 location=DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler
>   line=218 Failed to handle request [GET
>   http://localhost:10019/ext/stubhub/event/9874282/eventSectionZone]
>     reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactorRejectedExecutionException: Scheduler
>   unavailable   at
>   reactor.core.Exceptions.failWithRejected(Exceptions.java:249)     at
>   com.tu.sync.node.stubhub.remoterepository.EventRepository.lambda$getSectionZoneData$6(EventRepository.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec$StatusHandler.apply(DefaultWebClient.java:492)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.lambda$bodyToPublisher$5(DefaultWebClient.java:440)
>     at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)    at
>   org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.bodyToPublisher(DefaultWebClient.java:440)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.lambda$bodyToMono$0(DefaultWebClient.java:400)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)

Comment: your API-Method is missing a @RequestMapping. you should provide more information: when do you get the exceptions e.g.?

Comment: Thanks Gewure.  That was the issue. It got resolved.

Comment: Cool. I posted my comment as answer. If you could please accept it as answer to you question..!

Answer (score 0):

Your API-Method is missing a `@RequestMapping()`.

That should fix it.